# Header(Location) command is skipped

Tags: php, header, location

My header(Location) command does not execute.
Program simply skips that line.

On my code I have tried a lot of options.
With / without ob_start,
header command with ' or with ".
Space either side of : or both sides.
Execution continues as there is no header command.
I put some alerts before and after. I saw all of them.

...

```
}

else

{

ob_start();

header('Location:ordersummary.php');

}
```

...

This is my code. Copy and pasted. Simple and clean.
When I copy/paste target address to browser, page shows up without any problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the code reached the else block?

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: *"I put some alerts before and after. I saw all of them."* ... you can't output **anything** to the browser if you want a header redirect to work; the alerts would actually break it.

Comment: Using ob_start in that place is not going to fix any issues if you created output before already. And there should be a space between `Location:` and the URI.

Comment: Comments to all suggestions:
Yes, the code reached the else block. I checked that with <script><alert('zzz');></script>
Yes, I forgot to put exit() after header. But when I fixed, the code stopped on exit.
And at the beginning there was not an ob_start, I thought may be it was the reason.